# Ошибка при парсинге через JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
    public string[] cars { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    // Главный метод:
    static void Main()
    {
        System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
        String info = wc.DownloadString("http://slova.by/JSON_test/test.json");
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(File.ReadAllText(info));
        Console.WriteLine(obj.cars[2]);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Я скачиваю свой файл и ложу его в строку info. Но не хочет JSON его разбирать. Где я напортачил?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При чем здесь  `File.ReadAllText`?

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(info);
```

Comment: точно, это же не файл. :)
спасибо, заработало! 
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(info);